# Hide content after going to page 2 of archive, show content when back at first page

Tags: pagination

I want to hide the content below when the user uses pagination to move from the initial page of the archive (page 1). Is there some way of detecting whether or not the current page is page 1? Content below needs to reappear if the user returns to page 1.

```
<!--Hide Me if not on page one-->
<div class="oneThirdColumn alignLeft"> <!-- Rigth Column -->
  <div class="colTopHeader">
    <h2>Filter Products</h2>
    <div class="clear"></div>
  </div>
  <!-- Faceted Search -->
  <?php dynamic_sidebar( 'secondary-widget-area' ); ?>
</div> <!-- end Rigth Column -->
<!--Hide Me if not on page one-->
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an example on the wordpress codex. [(link)](http://codex.wordpress.org/Category_Templates#Text_Displaying_Only_on_First_Page_of_Archive). Basically you use an if statement on the variable `$paged` which stands keeps track of the current archive page.